# Emission and Base Colour Texture mirrored

Tags: texturing, emission

I'm relatively new to Blender. I purchased a model to use in some animation work I'm trying out.

There is a part of it which is supposed to be a screen. When ever I render a texture on this screen it seems to have the image, then the image is duplicated and mirrored on the same place and overlaps. This is really bad for when writing is supposed to be on the screen and I can't seem to fix this.

I have googled this quite a bit, found another "screen" which doesn't seem to be mirrored, checked the settings for both and they seem to be the same. This occurs whether the image is transparent or not. I am quite lost.

[image]

Comment: We can't help you without seeing e.g. the node setup or the geometry of the screen. First step should be to minify the .blend file to remove as much as possible while keeping the problem visible. A properly prepared .blend file showcasing a problem should have the texture reduced in size, packed, and everything should weigh below 200 kB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, it would be helpful if you could share your .blend file.
Before saving the .blend file, please go to File > External Data > Pack resources. This will ensure that the image texture you are using is included in the .blend file.

Based on your description and the image you posted, I believe this might be related to the geometry of your 'screen' object. Do you have a face on the front and the back? I think the material is being applied to a face which is pointed at the camera, AND a face that is pointing away from the camera. The face that is pointing away is the 'mirrored' image.

You could solve this by simply deleting the back face, or alternatively go to UV editing, select the UV for the back face, scale the UV down and move to an area of the image texture with no text.

Comment: Unfortunately as I purchased this model under the license I cannot just share it. 
Going into the UV for the object I did find a backface which was the culprit and have now been able to resolve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it's working :)